# Unable to install Java 6 and install 7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, apt-get

I am trying to install Java 7. I tested my Java version first, please see the below code

```
ubuadmin@ubuserver3:~/JavaJars/HelloWordGPU$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_30"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.1) (6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I tried uninstalling this first, using below command:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jdk
```

It gave me the following result.

```
ubuadmin@ubuserver3:~/JavaJars/HelloWordGPU$ sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-6-jdk is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuadmin@ubuserver3:~/JavaJars/HelloWordGPU$
```

I also tried using `sudo apt-get remove default-jdk` but same.

So how can I install Java 7?

Comment: I have 2 close votes here, without even quoting why!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I tried google. I visited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690143/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0, http://askubuntu.com/questions/139702/completely-uninstall-and-reinstall-openjdk, and http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java. That is why I came here.

Answer (score 1):

From the directions posted [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html),

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Then you can use [update-java-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-java-alternatives.8.html),

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
sudo update-java-alternatives -s <The correct Java 7 JDK>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. Why 90% of the user use `OpenJDK` in Ubuntu? Even in that link says "if you `really` want to install oracle"...

Comment: Because the Oracle JVM is not open source.

Comment: For the first command, it says `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

Answer (score 1):

You could install `openjdk-7-jdk` directly by

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

After that, you could use `update-java-alternatives` to set it as your default Java

```
update-java-alternatives -l
update-java-alternatives -s <jname>
```

Comment: I really don't understand what is wrong here. This is the output 
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree`
`Reading state information... Done`
`openjdk-7-jdk is already the newest version.`
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
`root@ubuserver3:/home/ubuadmin/JavaJars/HelloWordGPU# java -version`
`java version "1.6.0_30"`
`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.1) (6b30-1.13.1-`1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1)`
`OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)`
`root@ubuserver3:/home/ubuadmin/JavaJars/HelloWordGPU#`

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess It looks like you already installed `openjdk-7-jdk`. You could use `update-java-alternatives` to set it as your default java, please refer to the answer given by Elliott Frisch.

Comment: what does it ask for the next parameter? I am not a Linux person even I am doing this.

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess First part of the `-l` output.