# Running Grails With Connection To DB

Tags: database, grails

I would like to know what mistake I've made that, after I set my connection details, the log panel started to trace this in my grails app:
I a using NB 6.9 RC2 with Grails 2.4.3 and PostGreSQL 9.4

```
24/04/2016 07:31:11 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
ADVERTENCIA: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
24/04/2016 07:31:12 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
ADVERTENCIA: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
|Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
....................................
|Running Grails application
24/04/2016 07:31:29 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
ADVERTENCIA: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Error |
2016-04-24 07:31:51,632 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR spring.BeanBuilder  - WARNING: Your cache provider is set to 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' in DataSource.groovy, however the class for this provider cannot be found.
Using Grails' default cache region factory: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
Error |
2016-04-24 07:31:54,554 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
->> 632 | defineClassCond in java.lang.ClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   616 | defineClass in     ''
|   141 | defineClass in java.security.SecureClassLoader
|   283 | defineClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    58 | access$000 in     ''
|   197 | run      in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
|   190 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|   307 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   247 | forName  in java.lang.Class
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Thankx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690143/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Comment: you are using an older JDK than the one the postgres driver was built with.

Comment: I solved it cfrick !. Thanx for the link... It was the JDK version