# Unable to run Grails 2.1 with path set to Java 6

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-controller

I have an application that's built in **grails 2.1**
My environment variables are set to point to **JAVA 8** and **Grails 3.8** along with the path.
I am aware of the fact that **grails 2.1** has support upto **Java 6**. But I donot want to make changes to my environment variables in order to  make it point to Java 6. 
So I tried to set home and path for **java 6** and **grails 2.1** via command line. I was successful in doing so and echoe `%JAVA_HOME%`, `%GRAILS_HOME%` and `%PATH%` did show that values were set correctly.
 Trying to run the app with `grails run-app` command from under the project's root directory throws below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/grails/cli/GrailsCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.  Program will exit.
```

I tried to write a batch script that would set the `%JAVA_HOME%`, `%GRAILS_HOME%` and `%PATH%` to **Java 6** and **Grails 2.1** specific locations and then execute "grails run-app" from under the project's root directory, but while executing the script I got the same above error.

Below is how my batch script looks like:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Softwares\Java\Java-6\jdk1.6.0_41
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

set GRAILS_HOME=C:\Softwares\Grails\Grails_2.1.0
set PATH=%PATH%;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin

cd /D C:\MyWorkspace\MyApplication

grails run-app

REM pause
```

I have never written a batch script before.So, please correct me where possible.

Also, as for some restrictions in place I do not have the freedom of installing **SDKMan**.

Any guidance in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, why again do you intend versions that seriously outdated?

Comment: @GhostCat You are right. Is kind of a legacy application. So can't help it. I need to find a workaround.

Comment: I don't have much time right now. For the record: you understand the exception? It is telling you that you try to use a class within a jvm, but the class was compiled for a newer jvm. Are using the wrong GRAILS version?

Comment: run "java -version" before grails run-app. What is the output?

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks a lot for your time. What I understood from the exception is that it needs a different java runtime. But I dig more into it and found a better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690143/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout). I am new to this  grails framework. The version used i nmy project is **app.grails.version=2.1.0** atleast this is what my application.properties says.

Comment: @Rcordoval runnin java -version(in the same window where I run the script) gives me the one set in my system environmen tvariable, i.e. `java version "1.8.0_60"` 
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)` 
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to set environment variable in front of the existing PATH setting:

```
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;
```

This will lookup at the first match (the wanted version)}

Also, make sure you are using the exact same version of compile

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. placing the existing path after %JAVA_HOME%\bin made it work. The application is up and running now. So basically, what I understood is that the sequence does matter. Thanks again for pulling me out of this trouble.